# How do you trace docker images brought in by a pull?

Tags: docker

Pulling a docker image, the output typically includes something like:

```
604d05dfd165: Pull complete 
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete 
af271166b5e5: Pull complete 
ffff72610562: Pull complete 
f1eec3212a77: Pull complete 
e725d5f46b0c: Pull complete 
82633c2ea8fc: Pull complete 
1ec63dc1715b: Pull complete 
9be54d5ae146: Pull complete 
c3abf6246d6a: Pull complete 
03913f2c5b05: Pull complete
```

Those look like image id's. How can I trace what are the images that have those ID's?

Answer (score 1):

As `--tree` option for `docker images` was (sadly) removed, you can try [this](https://github.com/justone/dockviz)
as workaround.
Or maybe `docker images -a` will be enough for you.

Comment: `-a` doesn't show those images that show during `pull`. also tried with `--no-trunc` to that effect. E.g. when pulling `mongo`.

Comment: Are u sure? `images -a` should print all layers from `pull`. Take a peek for my `docker pull mongo` [here](https://gist.github.com/loadaverage/4c6428f4bcd5c88a1664)

Comment: hmmm looks like you're right, but how do you correlate from that list to what each image actually is? I see only numbers

Comment: Actually, without `--tree` command the are no way to easily to this. Many of images are just deps for what your pulled (e.g. mongo), due Docker layers nature and aufs/thin pool/overlayfs too.